# How to create MDI Form in Java

Tags: java, swing, jsr296

I am trying to create a desktop application where I have three forms for different tasks. Is there any way to create it as MDI in VB.net.

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1.

How to hide or show Internal frames on Click of Menuitems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to look at [Java Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) and [JInternalFrames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: I Have Created A Desktop Application i am Adding Internal Jframes but it is Showing on Both the I want to Hide Internal Jframe. how to do that..

Comment: then nothing better as you post code there, based on the http://sscce.org/ rulles, but I think that examples from tutorial covered this area too,